# ms sql scope_identity

Tags: sql-server-2008, syntax, scope-identity

I want to pass the id of the last inserted tuple in the stored procedure as an argument to another stored procedure.

Here are four snippets of code. The first two snippets works correctly:

```
declare @s bigint
select @s = scope_identity()
exec some_stored_proc @s
```

and

```
exec some_stored_proc scope_identity
```

But both these snippets cause query complete with errors:

```
declare @s bigint
select @s = scope_identity
```

and

```
exec some_stored_proc scope_identity()
```

I can't figure out what's the fuss with the brackets! How can `scope_identity()` have different syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesnt have different syntax

its a function and afunction should be executed by `()`

SCOPE_IDENTITY()

```
declare @s bigint
set @s = scope_identity()
exec some_stored_proc @s
```

should work.

### edit

`exec XXX` should get *"ready values"* and not *"calculated values"*. this is the reason why you **cant** send `datetime` as `getDate()`.

### edit2

acording to your sample  - i can send getDate without () to a sp.

[image]

it doesnt work. it has to go through @param

Comment: it DOES work. I just want to understand how does 'exec some_stored_proc scope_identity' work and why doesn't 'exec some_stored_proc scope_identity()' work.

Comment: why does 'exec some_stored_proc scope_identity' work? I use scope_identity like a variable here.

Comment: @superM we should use according to the syntax. maybe its a bug - didnt test it... there is no such thing scope_identity. its a function name which should be executed by ().

Comment: Yes, maybe it's just a bug. I just was really confused when it did work!

Comment: got confused because sql management studio painted it pink. ))) thanks a lot